# Snap store is not opening in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: "Gtk Locale not supported by C library"

Tags: snap, 20.04

I get this error.
Please help me!

```
3:44:31:0340 Gtk Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /usr/share/X11/xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /usr/share/X11/xkb
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: I've got the exact same problem!